# How to idiomatically convert from Option<T> to Result<T, ()>?

Tags: rust

I'm a Rust newbie! What's the best way to convert from an `Option<T>` to a `Result<T, ()>`?

The [TryFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait seems prevalent and returns a Result. The popular num_traits' [NumCast](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num_traits/cast/trait.NumCast.html) has many conversions but they all return an `Option<T>`. Similarly, as do the NonZero* constructors such as [NonZeroI32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroI32.html) in the *Rust Standard Library*. I then noticed that NumCast implements a `from()` that returns an `Option<T>` so I was thinking that maybe it had a non-standard way of doing things in general but then I saw the NonZero* implementations and questioned that idea.

Regardless, converting from Options to Results seem frequent and I haven't found a neat way to do yet. E.g.:

```rust
/// Add common conversion from an i32 to a non-zero i32.
impl TryFrom<Container<i32>> for Container<NonZeroI32> {
  type Error = ();
  fn try_from(container: Container<i32>) -> Result<Self, ()> {
    // NonZeroI32::new() returns an Option not a Result. Try a helper.
    Ok(Self(option_to_result(NonZeroI32::new(container.0))?))
  }
}

/// Helper function to convert from an Option to a Result (both types are
/// foreign and so is From).
fn option_to_result<T>(option: Option<T>) -> Result<T, ()> {
  if let Some(some) = option {
    Ok(some)
  } else {
    Err(())
  }
}
```

```rust
/// Add another common conversion from an i32 to an i16.
impl TryFrom<Container<i32>> for Container<i16> {
  type Error = ();
  fn try_from(container: Container<i32>) -> Result<Self, ()> {
    // NumCast::from() also returns an Option not a Result. Try map_or() instead
    // of the helper.
    Ok(Self(NumCast::from(container.0).map_or(Err(()), |x| Ok(x))?))
  }
}
```

(Above examples in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8342f289b6f43381516353446f723346).)

These NumCast, NonZero*, and TryFrom conversions seem common enough but my approach feels clumsy as though I'm pitting the Option and Result types against each other. I struggle with these conversions and also miss the fundamental point of the `Option` type given `Result<T,()>` feels similar.

So, what's the idiomatic way to convert an `Option<T>` to `Result<T,()>` in Rust 2018?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Option` has the [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) method, usable for exactly this (well, for more wide case, in fact, but your request fits here too):

```
fn option_to_result<T>(option: Option<T>) -> Result<T, ()> {
  option.ok_or(())
}
```

[Modified playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb940d5e52c653d8d0f59dacd546fe5d)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how I missed this but now it will be easy to find!